# ReactJS style component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components

I'm new to reactjs and I made a component like this:

```
<Row>
    <Column className="col-8 noPadding">
          <Text value={this.props.description} />
    </Column>
    <Column className="col-4 text-right noPadding">
          <Text {...this.props} />
    </Column>
</Row>
```

This works fine for me but if I'm using this component (named Autosuggest) I can't style it. I made a .css file (which works on other components) but it doesn't affect my Autosuggest control:

```
<AutoSuggest className="marginTop" {...this.props.formControlProps} description="test" value="test" />
```

CSS:

```
    .marginTop{
    margin-top: 3rem;
}
```

There is no margin for the Autosuggest control. I tried to change the color but it doesn't work too. 
Is the only way to style it, if you apply the styles in the component class?

Comment: Does `AutoSuggest` understand this prop?

Comment: take className as props in child component and use there

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers! Ok Autosuggest doens't have the property thats the mistake but how do it do it? So that Autosuggest knows that className is for styling?

Comment: Have you tried to import the css file in `AutoSuggest` component?

Answer (score 0):

Its solved just added a new property and set the className of the hosting  to the properties value. Thanks